# FileNotFoundException "/" getting removed from URL

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I get the below exception.

```
Failed to GET File Details from http://192.168.2.111/storage java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/192.168.2.111/storage/data/18-Apr-2017-ops (No such file or directory)

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to GET File Details from http://192.168.2.111/storage java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/192.168.2.111/storage/data/18-Apr-2017-ops (No such file or directory)
at com.billing.getlogs.GetLogsTest.countLinesOperationsUpload(GetLogsTest.java:222)
at com.billing.getlogs.GetLogsTest.GetLogsLineCountTest(GetLogsTest.java:264)
```

If you look, the URL after java.io.FileNotFoundException: only has one / in the after http:. The URL is read from a properties file. Is there any reason why this would be getting removed as the / character correctly appears in other parts of the url.

Comment: stack-trace is one thing but we clearly cant see whats going on without a code block...

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the problem is:

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(text));
   
 try {
              ......
        }

text is a url string. I think I shouldn't be using the FileInput stream as it isn't a file as such. Not to figure out what I should be using.

Comment: Please post your code, we can't help you if we don't know what are you doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

I changed

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(text));
```

to

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(text).openStream());
```

I had been trying to read the contents of a URL but my original code was for reading the contents of a file.